# paperclip 2.7.0 on ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, paperclip

I have a very old rails app (rails 2.3.10 and ruby 1.8.7) and we want to move it on another server.
I can reinstall all gems with same version except for paperclip 2.7. 
when i tried to install it i receive an error on activesupport, that it seems it require ruby 1.9.3. According with paperclip doc this shouldn't happens, some one of you can help me?
i tried with all gems except paperclip, with no gems, and installing an old version of activesupport. Below you can find my tests.

```
app@new-server:/home/app/current# sudo gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

app@new-server:/home/app/current# sudo gem install paperclip -v=2.7.0
Fetching: i18n-0.6.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.6.4
Fetching: multi_json-1.7.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed multi_json-1.7.7
Fetching: tzinfo-0.3.37.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-0.3.37
Fetching: minitest-4.7.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed minitest-4.7.5
Fetching: atomic-1.1.10.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed atomic-1.1.10
Fetching: thread_safe-0.1.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.1.0
ERROR:  Error installing paperclip:
    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

I also tried to install activesupport 2.3.10 (that according with paperclip doc match requirements but i receive the same error

```
"activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3."
```

regards

Mauro

Comment: please show your GemFile.

Comment: The problem is not related to GemFile, the installation of paperclip stuck before install rails app, i'm not able to install it without any other gem.

Comment: the problem may be due to installed 'activesupport' gem, that why i need to see gemfile. are you using RVM?

Comment: no i'm using ruby enterprise edition (but i got the same error on ubuntu ruby interpreter). About active support as you ca see above i tried to install paperclip without gems on the system so i suppose it should install the activesupport right version

Comment: are you using bundler?

Comment: i use bundler in our rails app, however i'm trying with normal gem

Comment: if you are using bundler the install the gem with bundler, first create a empty gemset and then do bundle install over there.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to build the gem manually and use the file from the pull request here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/pull/1270. - Ralph