# How do install paperclip gem on a ruby 1.8.7 system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, rails-i18n

I've got an app written for ruby 1.8.7 / rails 2.3.15 and I am stuck with paperclip. When I try to install the gem I get:

```
> ~$ gem install paperclip
ERROR:  Error installing paperclip:
i18n requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

When I install a 1.8.7 compatible version of i18n (0.6.x) I get the same error.

I saw some answer here >[paperclip 2.7.0 on ruby 1.8.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542588/paperclip-2-7-0-on-ruby-1-8-7), but this one is a few steps ahead (he's got problems with activesupport) and the answer (build the gem yourself) is way beyond my abilities.

Can anyone suggest a viable solution (upgrading the app to 1.9.3 is out of the question)?

Comment: Update Ruby, 1.8.7 is old & no longer supported

Comment: Rails 2.3.15 is similarly outdated, and is quite insecure. You might consider https://railslts.com/ if upgrading is not an option...

Comment: You can use paperclip gem version 2.4 [LINK](https://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip/versions/2.4.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself: Just use the -f option with gem install and it will install it regardless of dependencies. Thanks everyone. And, yes, I know the version is old and outdated and insecure, etc. Who cares, it works :)